# Div text flowing out of th

Tags: html, css

Within a table I am trying to position a text div vertically from bottom to top, with the top of the text positioned to the left side of the tablecell. When I do this, the text flows out of it's parent `<th>`. For this I use the following:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

table th {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  text-align: right;
}

table th div {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <div>Lorem ipsum gini fixum</div>
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

When I add text to the div, this text is flowing out of it's th. It looks like
[image: this]

How can I let the cell grow depending on the text length?

**UPDATE**
As I change the table class within my html, the text is no longer overflowing. It has something to do with that class. I will look into it.

**SOLVED**
The issue was the following: `table-layout: fixed; width:100%;`

Comment: can I see your whole code? html css

Comment: writing mode `tb-rl` is deprecated; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode

Comment: Good point. I changed it to vertical-rl now, but it looks the same.

Answer (score 0):

I have update code plz check it with your html. here HTML and CSS.

Update in CSS:

```
writing-mode: vertical-rl;
-webkit-writing-mode: vertical-rl;
-ms-writing-mode: vertical-rl;
```

```css
table { border-collapse:collapse; }
td, th {border: 1px black solid; padding: 3px; }
table th{
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    text-align: right;
}

table th div {
    writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    -webkit-writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    -ms-writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <th>test</th>
  <th>teststst</th>
  <th>test</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>test</th>
  <th><div>Lorem ipsum gini fixasdasdf asdfsdf asdfasdf asdaasdfasd fasdfsdfasdfa sdsdfasdafasd asdsdjkas flasdfa fasdfasdfadffum</div></th>
  <th>test</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>test</th>
  <th>teststst</th>
  <th>test</th>
</tr>
</table>
```

Its automatic extend your cell size.

Comment: I will try to find the issue using this example.

Comment: @Klyner please provide full code so we can more help to you. may be as per you screenshot any fixed width and height on it. if it is possible then update html and css related to table.

Comment: As I change the table class within my html, the text is no longer overflowing. It has something to do with that class. I will look into it.

Comment: May be other css overwirte/set fixed height and width for your cell. so facing this issue.

Comment: table-layout: fixed;  width:100%; was the issue!